Increasing default font size?
I've been working on a book recently and I had to increase the paper size to fit the pdf cover page but now all of the text is super tiny. So sorry if this is a dumb question, but how can I scale up the text size do that it looks normal?

Welcome TeX.se @Timotheum What class are you using? (a MWE would be welcome) Did you try the 12pt class option?

Which font? And is this about increasing the size on the cover or throughout the book or what?

Covers are usually printed on a larger size paper and cut to fit.

An easy solution might be to create the cover in a separate document so it doesn't influence your main text.

Ok, thanks I guess I'll just keep it separate
